# Files in subdirectory aren't found in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, readdir

I need somehow to loop over subdirectories but it returns me an error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'text3.txt'`
Here are the files I use:

```
main.js
files
|_file1.txt
|_file2.txt
dir
|_text3.txt
```

Here is my main.js:

```
fs = require('fs'), aes = require('aes256'),
key = 'abc';
  enc = file => {
   return aes.encrypt(key,file)
  }
  decr = encr => {
    return aes.decrypt(key,encr)
  }
    clf = dir => {
    files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
      // Filter files
      for(let i of files){
        stat = fs.statSync(i)
          if(stat.isFile()){
            newFiles.push(i)
          }
          else dirs.push(i)
        }
        // Encrypt folders
          for(let file of newFiles){
            fl = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
            fs.writeFileSync(file,enc(fl));
          }
    }
    clf('./')
    for(let c of dirs) clf(c);
```

Decrypt and ecnrypt func-s use aes256 encryption and return strings. Then clf function checks if files are not folders and pushes folders to an array. Then we encrypt files in main directory, but nothing happens in sub directories, it returns an error instead:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'text3.txt'
```

But text3.txt IS in dir directory!! Then why I have an error?

Comment: You really should declare your variables explicitly; in particular nothing ever clears `newFiles` when scanning a new directory

Answer (score 1):

First off, declare every single variable you use.  This is a recipe for disaster using undeclared variables.  I would not even attempt to work on code like this without first declaring every single variable to the proper scope using `let` or `const`.

Second, when you do `fs.statSync(i)`, the `i` here is just a plain filename with no path.  If you do `console.log(i)`, you will see it is only a filename.  So, to reference the right file, you have to add the path back onto it from the your `readdirSync(dir)` and then pass that full path to `fs.statSync()`.

You will find `path.join()` as a convenient way to combine a path with a filename.